# Query master_files table via linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am on SQL2008R2, and I try to query database files remotely via linked server, but the remote one (A) mix up the id's, and different database id's got totally different filenames next to it.
If I query the files locally on the target server, I got the proper file list.

--A

```
--remotely querying target server 
SELECT DB_NAME(a.database_id), a.* FROM [myLinkedServer].master.sys.master_files AS a WHERE DB_NAME(a.database_id) IN('db1','db2',...)
```

--B

```
--Run locally on target server
SELECT DB_NAME(a.database_id), a.* FROM master.sys.master_files AS a WHERE DB_NAME(a.database_id) IN('db1','db2',...)
```

Query A and B should be has the same result set.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `DB_NAME()` is evaluated on the local server.

Comment: Gordon, thank you, is there any way to call it on remote server? Or should I join to sys.databases, and have the name from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon wrote DB_NAME is evaluated on the local server.
I solved it to JOIN to sys.databases on the remote server, and get the name from there.

Thank you Gordon!